# GCC Inline Assembly 'Nd' constraint

Tags: gcc, x86, kernel, inline-assembly, osdev

I'm developing a small toy kernel in C. I'm at the point where I need to get user input from the keyboard. So far, I have implemented `inb` using the following code:

```
static inline uint8_t inb(uint16_t port) {
     uint8_t ret;
     asm volatile("inb %1, %0" : "=a"(ret) : "Nd"(port));
     return ret;
}
```

I know that the `"=a"` constraint means that `al/ax/eax` will be copied to `ret` as output, but I'm still confused about the `"Nd"` constraint. Can anyone provide some insight on why this constraint is necessary? Or why I can't just use a general purpose register constraint like `"r"` or `"b"`? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you targeting 16 bit code?

Comment: I'm targeting 32 bit code, as I'm using GRUB to load my kernel into protected mode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `in` instruction (returning a byte) can either take an immediate 8 bit value as a port number, or a port specified in the `dx` register. More on the `in` instruction can be found in the [instruction reference](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_139.html)  (Intel syntax) . The machine constraints being used can be found in the [GCC docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html#Machine-Constraints) . If you scroll down to `x86 family` you'll see:

> d
>
> ```
> The d register
> ```
>
> N
>
> ```
> Unsigned 8-bit integer constant (for in and out instructions).
> ```

Comment: Okay, thanks. This helped a lot. I have one final question however, if the `N` constraint only allows an immediate byte for  ports from 0-255, but the `d` constraint allows for the entire `dx` register, why wouldn't I use only the `d` constraint? I mean, what are the advantages of using both constraints?

Comment: @MichaelMorrow This is a hold over from the 8086/8088 days when saving space was often important. If you use an 8 bit immediate (for a port between 0-255) you don't need the extra instruction to move it to `DX` first (save space). If you wanted to  access a port 256-65535 you had to pass it in `DX`. You can specify an 8 bit (0-255) port number in `DX` but  you incur the extra penalty in space by having to move it to `DX` first.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow If you compile with optimizations (-O1, -O2, -O3) using "Nd" as a constraint, the assembler template will give a hint to the compiler if it sees a value being passed can fit in 8 bits and code the smaller version (without moving to `DX` first). If you just used "d" then there is no hint that the compiler can optimize the assembler code in the template and will use the longer form (with `DX` whether required or not). When I get a few minutes later I'll update my answer with all this info.